# Multiple Details on UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i've got a simple question. How to set up an UITableView with multiple details. I've got plist where i'm storing all the details.
This what I did for just one details.`cell.textLabel.text = [[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];`

What to do if I want 2 details on my cell?

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to set the type of cell you want, if you want a title plus detail you can do this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

then for setting the title and detail labels, just

```
[cell textLabel].text = @"some title"
[cell detailTextLabel].text = @"some detail text"
```

Comment: Thanks.. Probably my question was not clear.. My cell is working everything is set up. Just I want to put 2 details.

Comment: So when you say 2 details, you are talking about the total of 2 text labels in your cell or one title label plus two extra detail labels, as in a total of three? Cause if you want the total of three you have to create a custom cell view and you can follow ÐąrέÐέvils answer, but if you want just two in total, you have to init your cell with the `initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` and then just set the `detailTextLabel`

Comment: Alright, then you need to create a custom cell view. You can try this [tutorial](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/03/28/customize-a-uitableviewcell-in-cellforrowatindexpath-part-1-no-need-to-subclass-uitableviewcell/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set style for the cell

[have look into this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html)

Comment: I set up the style 'cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];' but i can put just 1 details.

Comment: cell.textLabel.text=@"Some text"; cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Another line of text";

Answer (score 0):

If your not happy with using `cell.detailTextLabel` and one of the provided styles(set up from storyboard) then one option would be to create a custom `UITableViewCell`.

You can either create a xib and drag and drop a cell in and customize it from there or if your only using 1 table it may be easier to use a prototype cell and customize it directly in your table. The key part is to create a new Class to support your cell.